# Helper for matching players in a video game

Tags: c

**Terminology:**

Host - Spectator and summoner of players involved in the 1v1 matches

Player - A player who is participating in the 1v1 matches

Phantom - A player summoned for a 1v1 (present in the host's game)

Summon - Bringing a player into the host's game (where the host can spectate the match)

**Concept:**

The goal of this program is to allow a host to summon players in a fair order. Starting off there will be zero players in the summon queue. Each time a player is summoned the host will type their name into the program which will do either:

1. Detect this player has not been summoned before and add their name to the bottom of the queue
2. Detect this player has been summoned before:

   a. Player was summoned in the expected order - cycle the queue as normal

   b. Player 'jumped' the queue - move player to bottom of the queue then cycle

**Note:**

I know there are unused functions - I plan on using them in the future. I am posting this code for your review at it's earliest stage, so that I can rectify problems and not continue to use bad programming practices.

In the future I would like to add priority ordering for players who have joined the play session later using the `PLAYER->Fights`

The game is Dark Souls by the way.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 32

typedef unsigned int bool;

typedef struct DLINKED_LIST {
  struct _DLINKED_LIST *pPrev;
  struct _DLINKED_LIST *pNext;
} DLINKED_LIST;

typedef struct PLAYER {
  DLINKED_LIST Header;
  char *Player;
  unsigned int *Fights;
  unsigned int *Wins;
  unsigned int *Losses;
} PLAYER;

// Pointer to the player who was summoned last
struct PLAYER* Last;

// Function Declarations
void* forEachElement(PLAYER* Start, void (*func)(struct PLAYER*));
char* handleInput();
struct PLAYER* lookupPlayer(char* player);
void printSummonOrder(struct PLAYER* pCurrent);
void printElementContent(struct PLAYER* pCurrent);
struct PLAYER* createPlayer(char* player);
bool insertElementBefore(struct PLAYER* pCurrent, struct PLAYER* pNew);
bool insertElementAfter(struct PLAYER* pCurrent, struct PLAYER* pNew);  // Could be implemented as a wrapper for 'insertElementBefore'
bool removeElement(struct PLAYER* pCurrent);
bool swapTwoElements(struct PLAYER* pSwapFirst, struct PLAYER* pSwapSecond);
bool moveElementAfter(struct PLAYER* pToMove, struct PLAYER* pStatic);

// Function Definitions
void* forEachElement(PLAYER* Start, void (*func)(struct PLAYER*)) {

  if(!Start) Start = Last;
  PLAYER* pWorking = Start;
  do {
    func(pWorking);
    pWorking = pWorking->Header.pNext;
  } while(pWorking != Start);

  return 0;
}

char* handleInput() {

  printf("Who has just been summoned? : ");

  // Removing newline character from input string
  char* input = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
  fgets(input, MAX_NAME_LENGTH, stdin);
  if(input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n') {
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
  }

  // Debug Functions
  if(input[0] == '#') {
    forEachElement(Last, printElementContent);
    printf("Special Function #\n");
    return 0;
  }
  if(input[0] == 'L') {
    printElementContent(Last);
    return 0;
  }
  // TODO ability to remove players from the queue
  // TODO ability to update 'Fights', 'Wins' and 'Losses'

  // Use return value to choose between restarting the while(1) loop or continuing
  return input;
}

PLAYER* lookupPlayer(char* player) {

  PLAYER* pWorking = Last;

  do {
    if(!strcmp(player, pWorking->Player)) return pWorking;
    pWorking = pWorking->Header.pNext;
  } while(pWorking != Last);

  return 0;
}

void printSummonOrder(struct PLAYER* pCurrent) {

  signed int short order = 1;
  PLAYER* pWorking = pCurrent->Header.pNext;
  PLAYER* pHolding = pWorking;
  do {
    printf("[%d] - %s\n", order, pWorking->Player);
    pWorking = pWorking->Header.pNext;
    order++;
  } while(pWorking != pHolding);

  return;
}

void printElementContent(struct PLAYER* pCurrent) {

  // TODO tidy this function
  printf("------\n");
  printf("%s Element\n", pCurrent->Player);
  PLAYER* pNext = pCurrent->Header.pNext;
  printf("pNext = %s\n", pNext->Player);
  PLAYER* pPrev = pCurrent->Header.pPrev;
  printf("pPrev = %s\n", pPrev->Player);
  printf("Fights = %d\n", pCurrent->Fights);
  printf("Wins   = %d\n", pCurrent->Wins);
  printf("Losses = %d\n", pCurrent->Losses);
  printf("------\n");
  return;
}

struct PLAYER* createPlayer(char* player) {

  PLAYER* NewPlayer = (PLAYER*)malloc(sizeof(PLAYER));
  NewPlayer->Player = (char*)malloc(strlen(player));
  strcpy(NewPlayer->Player, player);
  NewPlayer->Fights = 0;
  NewPlayer->Wins   = 0;
  NewPlayer->Losses = 0;
  return NewPlayer;
}

bool insertElementBefore(struct PLAYER* pCurrent, struct PLAYER* pNew) {

  // Get the pointer to the previous element
  PLAYER* pBefore = (PLAYER*)pCurrent->Header.pPrev;

  // Update element before pCurrent (pBefore) to have it's pNext point to pNew
  pBefore->Header.pNext = pNew;

  // Update pNew to have it's pPrev point to pBefore
  pNew->Header.pPrev = pBefore;

  // Update pNew to have it's pNext point to pCurrent
  pNew->Header.pNext = pCurrent;

  // Finally update pCurrent to have it's pPrev point to pNew
  pCurrent->Header.pPrev = pNew;

  return 1;
}

bool insertElementAfter(struct PLAYER* pCurrent, struct PLAYER* pNew) {

  // Get the pointer to the following element
  PLAYER* pAfter = (PLAYER*)pCurrent->Header.pNext;

  // Update element after pCurrent (pAfter) to have it's pPrev point to pNew
  pAfter->Header.pPrev = pNew;

  // Update pNew to have it's pNext point to pAfter
  pNew->Header.pNext = pAfter;

  // Update pNew to have it's pPrev point to pCurrent
  pNew->Header.pPrev = pCurrent;

  // Finally update pCurrent to have it's pNext point to pNew
  pCurrent->Header.pNext = pNew;

  return 1;
}

bool removeElement(struct PLAYER* pCurrent) {

  PLAYER* pNext = (PLAYER*)pCurrent->Header.pNext;
  PLAYER* pPrev = (PLAYER*)pCurrent->Header.pPrev;

  // Update pPrev's pNext to be pNext
  pPrev->Header.pNext = pNext;

  // Likewise update pNext's pPrev to be pPrev (removing references to pCurrent from surrounding elements)
  pNext->Header.pPrev = pPrev;

  return 1;
}

bool swapTwoElements(struct PLAYER* pSwapFirst, struct PLAYER* pSwapSecond) {

  // Is the first element BEFORE and ADJACENT to the second?
  if(pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev == pSwapSecond) {
    pSwapFirst->Header.pNext = pSwapSecond->Header.pNext;   // Updates pSwapFirst's pNext to be pSwapSecond's pNext
    pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev = pSwapSecond;
    pSwapSecond->Header.pPrev = pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev;   // Updates pSwapSecond's pPrev to be pSwapFirst's pPrev
    pSwapSecond->Header.pNext = pSwapFirst;
    return 1;
  }
  // Is the first element AFTER and ADJACENT to the second?
  if (pSwapFirst->Header.pNext == pSwapSecond) {
    pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev = pSwapSecond->Header.pPrev;  // Updates pSwapFirst's pPrev to be pSwapSeconds's pPrev
    pSwapFirst->Header.pNext = pSwapSecond;
    pSwapSecond->Header.pNext = pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev;   // Updates pSwapSeconds's pNext to be pSwapFirst's pNext
    pSwapSecond->Header.pPrev = pSwapFirst;
    return 1;
  }

  // Update (pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev)->Header.pNext to point to pSwapSecond
  PLAYER* pBeforeSwapFirst = pSwapFirst->Header.pPrev;
  pBeforeSwapFirst->Header.pNext = pSwapSecond;
  // Update (pSwapFirst->Header.pNext)->Header.pPrev to point to pSwapSecond
  PLAYER* pAfterSwapFirst = pSwapFirst->Header.pNext;
  pAfterSwapFirst->Header.pPrev = pSwapSecond;
  // Update (pSwapSecond->Header.pPrev)->Header.pNext to point to pSwapFirst
  PLAYER* pBeforeSwapSecond = pSwapSecond->Header.pPrev;
  pBeforeSwapSecond->Header.pNext = pSwapFirst;
  // Update (pSwapSecond->Header.pNext)->Header.pPrev to point to pSwapFirst
  PLAYER* pAfterSwapSecond = pSwapSecond->Header.pNext;
  pAfterSwapSecond->Header.pPrev = pSwapFirst;

  return 1;
}

bool moveElementAfter(struct PLAYER* pToMove, struct PLAYER* pStatic) {

  // Step 1: Update pStatic->Header.pNext to point to pToMove
  PLAYER* pOriginalAfterStatic = pStatic->Header.pNext;
  pStatic->Header.pNext = pToMove;
  // Step 2: Update pOriginalAfterStatuc->Header.pPrev to point to pToMove
  pOriginalAfterStatic->Header.pPrev = pToMove;
  // Info: This has inserted pToMove after pStatic and before pOriginalAfterStatic (from the perspective on pStatic and pOriginalAfterStatic)
  // Step 3: Stitch up the elements before and after pToMove's original position
  PLAYER* pBeforeToMove = pToMove->Header.pPrev;
  PLAYER* pAfterToMove  = pToMove->Header.pNext;
  pBeforeToMove->Header.pNext = pAfterToMove;
  pAfterToMove->Header.pPrev = pBeforeToMove;
  // Step 4: Finally update the Header for pToMove
  pToMove->Header.pPrev = pStatic;
  pToMove->Header.pNext = pOriginalAfterStatic;

  return 0;
}

int main() {

  printf("Summon Cycles\n");

  char* first = handleInput();
  if(!first) return -1;

  PLAYER *Head = createPlayer(first);
  printSummonOrder(Head);

  // Initialise the pointer to the last USED element
  Last = Head;

  while(1) {

    char* input = handleInput();
    if(!input) continue;

    PLAYER* Exists = lookupPlayer(input);
    if(Exists) {
      if(Last->Header.pNext != Exists) {
        printf("%s jumped the queue\n", Exists->Player);
        moveElementAfter(Exists, Last);
      } else continue;
      Exists->Fights += 1;
      Last = Exists;  // Important to update this
      printSummonOrder(Last);
      continue;
    } else {
      PLAYER* New = createPlayer(input);
      // Insert player into linked last (after most recent element)
      insertElementAfter(Last, New);
      //printLinkedList(Head);
      printSummonOrder(New);
      // Set the Last element to the newly added one
      Last = New;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I am compiling this using the following Makefile:

```
all:
    gcc main.c -o main.elf
```

Comment: I suggest you compile this with the `-wall` switch that you get all the warning messages. Have you run this code and does it work. You might also want to see if there is a `lint` program available for your system.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yes, I've compiled and executed the binary - it does work as intended. The functionality is very basic at the moment though. I get alot of warning messages with and without that flag. Most of them are due to assigning pointers to incompatable types. I've Googled 'lint' and for sure it's available on my system (Kubuntu). I will mess around with it :) Thanks for your comment!

Comment: To be honest with you, this code only "works" because it does nothing so far. The warning messages about `incompatable type` is a clear indication that this code will crash and burn in the future.

Comment: @pacmaninbw It's only because I'm casting _DLINKED_LIST pointers as PLAYER pointers. I think replacing the DLINKED_LIST pointers in the DLINKED_LIST structure to PLAYER pointers might fix it. "Crash and burn in the future" - hence why I'm posting the code at this early stage so I don't continue to write bad code.

Comment: The rules of the site says the code has to work as expected, it also says the code has to do something. Unfortunately this code just isn't ready for review on this web-site. Some suggestions, separate the code for PLAYER and DLINKED_LIST into their own files PLAYER.h, PLAYER.c, DLINKED_LIST.h DLINKED_LIST.c, keep the concepts separate. DLINKED_LIST might need a data field that is PLAYER, although since PLAYER currently contains a DLINKED_LIST pointer I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Get as much functionality as you can going and then once it is basically working with a few bugs ask for help on stackoverflow.com, but make sure to follow their rules.

Comment: It does work as expected, just my expectations are rather low. Currently it does exactly what I decribed in the "Concept" part of my post. However, what's done is done - remove my post..

Comment: If you can sort out the specific compiler warnings and create a minimal example focusing only on those, then you can ask how to fix those on SO. At a glance, it seems that you should re-design the structs and keep linked list logic separate from data. For example you could create a simple, stand-alone linked list ADT in a separate file, that uses void pointers to data.

Comment: I don't agree with this being irreparably broken, but I do agree that it doesn't do enough to be reviewable. VTC.